# Carrierwave converting PDF to JPG (MiniMagick)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

I have a problem creating JPG thumbnails for PDF files.

I'm using Carrierwave. Imagemagick is properly installed. There are no problems creating thumbnails of PNG, JPG or GIF files.

Here is the code I use

```
version :thumb, :if => :image? do
    storage :file

        begin
            process :convert => 'jpg' # this should do the trick but doesn't
            process :resize_to_fill => [160,160]
            process :quality => 95
            process :set_content_type
            process :set_thumb_attr => true
            def full_filename (for_file = model.file.file) 
                "#{model.slug}-thumb.jpg" 
            end
        rescue Exception => e
            puts e.inspect
            true
        end
end

def set_thumb_attr(val)
    model.thumb = val
end


def image?(new_file)
    model.mime.include? 'image/' or model.mime.include? '/pdf'
end

def set_content_type(*args)
    self.file.instance_variable_set(:@content_type, "image/jepg")
end
```

The content of the thumbnail suggests that the created file is still a PDF-file.

> %PDF-1.3
>   1 0 obj
>   <<
>   /Pages 2 0 R
>   /Type /Catalog
>   ...

I appreciate any suggestions / solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was

```
process :quality => 95
```

It reprocessed the PDF. Removing that line resolved my problem.