# Preview of PDF while using Minimagick and Carrierwave in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, carrierwave, minimagick

I've been trying to develop a site that allows for the uploading of various types of documents including pdfs. Below is my uploader:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

def store_dir
 "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

version :jpg do
 process :convert_to_images
 process :set_content_type_jpg

def convert_to_images(*args)
 image = MiniMagick::Image.open(current_path)
 image.pages.each_with_index do |page, index|
  MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |convert|
   convert.background 'white'
   convert.flatten
   convert.density 300
   convert.quality 95
   convert << page.path
   convert << "#{CarrierWave.root}/#{store_dir}/image-#{index}.jpg"
  end
 end
end
end        

def set_content_type_jpg(*args)
self.file.instance_variable_set(:@content_type, "image/jpg")
end

def extension_whitelist
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf)
end

end
```

So far the site will allow uploads to the server of all of the whitelisted file types, and everything but pdfs will actually display. Pdfs, however, will only show a broken image rather than an image of that pdf. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked out [link] (https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/288) ? Perhaps check to see the file type and then try the code suggested by janko-m on the linked page

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert the pdf into a jpg or other image as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036746/carrierwave-converting-pdf-to-jpg-minimagick) Then try to run the converted file through your above code

Comment: Ok. I put that code above everything else within the block and now I'm getting an "undefined method `mime'" error.